# Update column value based on row value in the same row, row by row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I have a table with `memberID` and `Date` like this:

```
MEM_ID          DATE        ttl_sales
-------------------------------------
19960124000007  2020-01-19  NULL
19960131001079  2020-01-20  NULL
19960203001249  2020-01-07  NULL
19960205000213  2020-01-14  NULL
```

I need to update `ttl_sales` from a `sales_table`, with condition that using `MEM_ID` from the same row and transactions that happened before the `DATE` from the same row.

I might need to use similar function but with more complicate conditions (before give DATE plus transacted in certain stores, with certain products etc.) in the future, so both related key words and solutions are welcome.

I am using SQL Server.

Thank you.

Comment: Request you to provide the expected output and what if you have tried anything so far with the expected output clarifications/logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way is to coordinate a subquery that sums the rows in sales based on the members mem_id:

```
UPDATE members
SET ttl_sales = (
  SELECT sum(s.amount) 
  FROM sales s 
  WHERE s.sale_date < members.[date] and s.mem_id = members.mem_id
)
```

I've assumed ttl_sales is the total of sales amounts. If it's a count, use `COUNT(*)` instead of `SUM(amount)`

You can add more clauses to the WHERE to tolerate your requirements for products, stores etc

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, you can use an updatable CTE and window functions.  For instance, if you wanted the cumulative number, you would use `row_number()`:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by memberId order by date) as seqnum
      from t
     )
update toupdate
     set ttl_sales = seqnum;
```

Window functions are very flexible, so they can probably do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Common Table Expression containing a subquery with `INNER JOIN` and `SUM` aggregation :

```
WITH s AS
(
 SELECT s.Mem_ID AS Mem_ID_s, 
        SUM( COALESCE(s.ttl_sales,0) ) AS ttl_sales_s
   FROM sales s
   JOIN members m 
     ON m.Mem_ID = s.Mem_ID
  WHERE s.Date < m.Date
  GROUP BY s.Mem_ID
)
UPDATE m
   SET m.ttl_sales = s.ttl_sales_s
  FROM members as m
  INNER JOIN s 
     ON m.Mem_ID = s.Mem_ID_s;
```

Also note that using `COALESCE()` function is important for the cases of `NULL` values for `ttl_sales` column.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=57a02ed5175d98a59f7daab58051be7f)</kbd>

Comment: Consider that preserving NULL in the SUM might be desirable to know the difference between `-1 + 1` vs `(no records)`

Comment: well, Ok that might be another option too @CaiusJard